# Separar los 'loadChildren' cuando se haga el 'ng build --prod'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modular

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Angular 8+, y necesito cambiar la distribución de las carpetas al hacer el build.
Tengo actualmente esta configuración en mi `routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'App1', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app1.module#App1Module' },
    { path: 'App2', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app2.module#App2Module' },
    { path: 'App3', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app3.module#App3Module' },
    ...
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer el `ng buid --prod` los módulos que definí en el routing quiero que se encapsule dentro de una carpeta diferente al `dist`, quiero lograr algo así.

```
. // <- project
├── ...
├── dist
│   ├── app
│   |   ├── assets/
│   |   ├── main.js
│   |   ├── polyfills.js
│   |   ├── runtime.js
│   |   ├── style.css
│   |   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── moduleApp1/
│   |   |   ├── module-app1.js
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   │   ├── moduleApp2/
│   |   |   ├── module-app2.js
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   │   ├── moduleApp3/
│   |   |   ├── module-app3.js
│   |   |   ├── ...
```

que configuración debería hacer para poder lograr esta estructura de archivos dentro de la carpeta dist?

Comment: Que has intentado o consultado ?

Comment: intente usar webpack, pero no he logrado lo que quería.

Comment: edita tu pregunta y sube lo que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor.